# upload image to wikimedia with php

Tags: php, api, image-uploading, wikimedia

i am loged in to wikimedia server with the api and not able to upload
i get this error:
thanks i got this error back,

**File upload param file is not a file upload; be sure to use multipart/form-data for your POST and include a filename in the Content-Disposition header**

here is the code of the image upload:

```
$postdata = "action=upload&format=php&filename=Image.jpg&file=@".realpath("Image.jpg")."&token=" . urlencode($_SESSION["csrftoken"]);

$app["curloptionscostun"] = array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE =>$CookieFile,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $app["useragent"],
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $app["curloptionscostun"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $app["apiURL"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$result = unserialize(curl_exec($ch));
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo "Error 004: " . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: you're simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong. if curl_exec fails, it returns boolean false, which you then try to unserialized. try `$res = curl_exec(...); if ($res === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` and see what comes out.

Comment: thanks now i can catch the error

Comment: don't do file uploads like that. curl will accept an array of key=value pairs, and WILL detect `@filename`-type uploads in the array. but it will NOT pull apart a pre-made query string and check it for @filename-type constructs.

Comment: can you show me exmple of how should i do it (i am new with using curl)

Answer (score 0):

is this better?

```
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
        'action' =>'upload',
        'format'=>'php',
        'filename'=>'Image.jpg',
        'token' => urlencode($_SESSION["csrftoken"]),
        'file' => '@' . realpath('Image.jpg')
));
```